# Immersive Mode on WebView Application - Text input is covered

Tags: android, android-layout

I've written a basic application to test the way Immersive Mode or FullScreen mode(only hide status bar) works on a Webview app.

Here's my main_activity. Note this is just a test app that follows the api guidelines as far as I can tell.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://baidu.com"); //just a test website, doesn't matter really. Just need a text box low enough on screen.
    setupFullscreenMode();
}

private void setupFullscreenMode() {
    View decorView = setFullscreen();
    decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    setFullscreen();
                }
            });
}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        setFullscreen();
    }
}

private View setFullscreen() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    //FLAG ORDERING MAKES A DIFFRENCE
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE // without the other layout flags, this results in glitched out status and navagation spaces
                    //unsurprisingly everything (pre-selected scenario etc) works fine with this flag, but it's not true fullscreen
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION // This also breaks the pre-seclected scenario
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN // This breaks the pre-selected scenario
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION //2
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN //1
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);//3 with 1,2,3 there's some glitching still going on(ghost statusbar)
    return decorView;
}
```

In short this is my bug -

1. Be in immersive mode and go to a website (baidu in this case) and search for anything..
2. Scroll down to the text input box and click it. The application should have resized with the input box right above the top of the keyboard.
3. Hit the little "downward" triangle to dismiss the keyboard. Notice how the input field is left selected still.
4. (ISSUE) Scroll up enough to lower the input box on screen. Now try tapping on the input box again. The app doesn't resize to accommodate the keyboard.

Expected Behaviour would be to resize the app because that's what happens when I try doing this without fullscreen or immersive mode.

What is going on here that results in a failure ? 
In my actual app this is very frustratingly flaky. It may or may not resize the app whether or not the text box is pre-selected.

For now, I'm only interested in understanding this test app's behavior.

Comment: as with many other android bugs, have you tested this with multiple devices?

Comment: Yup, I have. 2 Nexus 5s on 5.0 and a Nexus 6 on 5.1